# Reducer execution on each subordinate node

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

I wanted to specify one theoretical question (for some reason I had some doubts): if the quantity of reducers in run command isn't set, on each subordinate node one reducer will be executed?

Answer (score 0):

No. Only One reducer will be run anywhere on the cluster. All your map keys and values will reach that single reducer